# work on the files in a directory using html javascript

Tags: javascript, html, client-side

Trying to see if this is possible -

1.) User logs into our site
2.) Points to a directory
**3.) The javascript code reads contents of the directory, shows thumbnails for any jpeg/gif in those directories. This all without uploading all the photos to the server. Kind of a semi desktop app.**

Point 3 is something I have never done, is this possible for an online application to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this...***yet*** (unless you're using a prerelease of Chrome 9). There are [some APIs coming down the pike](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/) that will make this possible in browsers that support them; there's a description of using them [in this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/file/filesystem/).

But right now, no. To do this, you'll need to use a technology that allows local file access, such as a *signed* Java applet (normal unsigned ones obviously can't do this) or, on a severely limited number of platforms and browsers, an ActiveX control.

**Update**: Sorry, the new JavaScript APIs I mentioned above **don't** give you (user-granted) access to any old directory on their system. They do give you access to the file system, but it's a sandboxed file system. So you'd have to have the users move the files into the sandbox (which you could do via the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/) and with [drag-and-drop](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/04/google-turns-to-html5-for-gmails-new-drag-and-drop-attachments/), keeping it an entirely client-side thing, no uploading required). But that isn't quite what you described.

Comment: As I understand, that just allows you to create files; you cannot read an existing directory.

Comment: @SLaks: You're both correct and incorrect. :-) In reverse order: It doesn't just allow you to create files; you can read files (and directories) as long as they're in the sandboxed file system. But you're quite correct, I hadn't looked closely at the directory stuff and I think, looking again, that it doesn't allow (user granted) access to directories outside the sandbox. I've updated.

Comment: Can I do this by a standalone HTML5 application ?

Comment: @Planet: Sure, you can use a platform like Adobe AIR or XULRunner or Prism (I haven't done it, myself): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869613/html5-for-desktop-application-development (XULRunner isn't really HTML5, but it's a lot of the same technologies.)

Answer (score 1):

No; this is not possible.

Javascript cannot directly interact with the user's local filesystem

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to access any of the clients files using JavaScript as that would be a security risk.