# How to package an html webpage such as html, js, css into a single .exe executable program file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, executable

I wrote an example of a web page lottery written in jQuery, which was changed according to some examples.
I want to turn it into an `.exe` executable.

How can I do that?

The file structure is as follows:

```
jquery-app
|-----css
| |--demo.css
|-----images
| |--1.jpg
| |--2.jpg
| |--......
|-----js
| |--awardRotate.js
| |--jquery.min.js
|
|-----index.html
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16584589/3462319

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert web application into desktop executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29686011/how-do-i-convert-web-application-into-desktop-executable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electron is the most used framework for this. It's not going to be a simple copy/paste into a wrapper, if that is what you are asking for, but it's got a lot going for it - good docs and a great community. Bit of a memory hog though.

https://www.electronjs.org/

You could also use Visual Studio to create a new windows application and use a web view as a wrapper, but I'm not sure if the browser code is bundled with that; or if it uses a natively installed browser at runtime.