# Using Javascript and JQuery to create a desktop application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, desktop

I am wondering if it is possible to create a desktop application using HTML 5 technologies?

I have decent web skills and all I need access to is the hard drive for saving files, loading them, etc.

The application would be a set of HTML pages but then it would use a browser, but then it should allow access to the hard drive.

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think it would be possible through a normal browser, however you may be able to get something like this to work through adobe air or a similar type of application.

Comment: You mean like [***this***](http://www.jquery4u.com/user-interface/jquery-windows-7-style-website/). [**Live Demo**](http://www.soyos.net/tl_files/demos/Windows-7-UI-and-Windows-Aero-for-Websites/)

Comment: I think is possible with backbone.js or knockout.js and for saving files use localstorage.

Comment: Take a look at : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869613/html5-for-desktop-application-development][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869613/html5-for-desktop-application-development

Comment: I wouldn't use jQuery in a controlled environment like a desktop app, it's too much overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Create secure ebooks and desktop applications from your websites, HTML or PDF documents using [HTML Executable](http://www.htmlexe.com/Home). Offer your websites and presentations as stand-alone desktop applications to your customers and visitors (one EXE).

Or you can try downloading either the [Gecko Engine](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko%3aHome_Page) or [WebKit Engine](http://www.webkit.org/) and build an application on it! :)

Or you would be searching for [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/), which is a windowless port of Chromium/WebKit. API is available for C++ and .NET on Windows, Mac OSX, and Linux.