# html5 vs adobe air vs java for desktop application?

Tags: java, html, apache-flex, air

I need suggestions regarding language I can use to develop an application that excels aesthetically and functionally. As I am expecting html5 to be on top of the preference for many people the what is recommended API for developing html5 "desktop" application.

Thanks

Comment: I would say that it is very important to know what will your app do. As soon as you want it to look nice I would go for HTML5 or AIR. But Java is also an option when it comes to low level stuff or security. Also an important factor is how confortable/advanced are you with any of the languages.

Comment: I voted to close; as this is not a specific programming question.  Please be sure to read the FAQ for details on appropriate StackOverflow questions: http://stackoverflow.com/faq .  I'll add that you can build an applications with HTML/JavaScript and deploy them to desktop computers using Adobe AIR.

Answer (score 0):

There is another topic about programming Desktop Applications with web-devel languages.

[How to develop Desktop Apps using HTML/CSS/JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232784/how-to-develop-desktop-apps-using-html-css-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

The choice is completely upto you. Because everything has some ups and downs. But if you are very much interested in developing using HTML5 and JavaScript. There are lot of sdk's available. Tidesdk and Appjs will minimize the work load for you.

Please go through these links.

[Solutions for distributing HTML5 applications as desktop applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869613/html5-for-desktop-application-development)
[How to develop Desktop Apps using HTML/CSS/JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232784/how-to-develop-desktop-apps-using-html-css-javascript)